# Sudden bluetooth mouse lag ONLY on ubuntu 19.04 MX anywhere 2s

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, 19.04

Yes, i know. Thousandth thread on this issue(cmon, dont yall get the hint that something's wrong lol). I've tried every fix on google and came up with nothing.

Context: Been happily using(sort of) ubuntu 19.04 for awhile now. And one day after unplugging my laptop for a meeting and replugging it back in, the bluetooth mouse i use start to lag. Badly. Tearing my hair out at this point since i only have one mouse. Never had these issues on mac or windows. Jesus. Not to mention the display driver issues when using a Nvidia laptop( rant for another day)

Could i get a suggestion on how to fix this?

As per my googling skills i've tried

```
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlopt.conf
```

with zero success. Thanks in advance :(

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679811/583995 Here is the solution I found after searching for a few hours

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mostly fix the lag issue by connecting the mouse using the unifying receiver.

Afterwards the mouse did react far better when connected via bluetooth, although not perfect.

- Mouse used: Logitech MX anywhere 2s
- Distro: Ubuntu 19.04
- Kernel: 5.0.0-32-generic

Answer (score 0):

The laggy bluetooth mouse problem is a know issue and you can use the following workaround:

*(Taken from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1824559/comments/10 and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1857256)*:

```
sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy/info
```

where `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` is the address of your Bluetooth adapter and `yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy` is address of your Bluetooth mouse. Add the following lines to this file and save your changes:

```
[ConnectionParameters]
MinInterval=6
MaxInterval=7
Latency=0
Timeout=216
```

Then restart your Bluetooth service:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

This solution also works after rebooting your system.